# How to get all roles list from Tomcat in Java EE application

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, web

I have a Java EE application and I want get a list of all roles from Tomcat and show them in a combo box in my application. Tomcat is configured to read the users and roles from a database.

How can I do this?

Comment: JEE apps do not run on Tomcat. Tomcat is not an app server.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the enumeration of all existing roles is not part of the standardization - you can configure Tomcat with various realms - from a simple xml file to LDAP or various database integrations. Or a combination thereof. Or an SSO system.

For this reason, enumerating all different roles that might be available is a function that your user database of choice must provide.

Is it possible to get them? Yes. Can you get them "from Tomcat"? No. At least not in a simple and generic way. You'll have to know which exact realm has been configured and access its datastore. Some of the realms might even require a restart of tomcat in order to use changed data.